# How to downgrade VLC 2.0.1 to 1.1.x?

Tags: vlc, downgrade, 12.04

I haven't added any VLC PPA's and I have no clue how to solve this problem.

If it's not possible to downgrade VLC, Running VLC in a portable mode is sufficient for me. I need the older version only for compatibility with a particular Android app.

System specs:

```
AMD PhenomX4,
2GiB RAM,
GeForce6100PM-M2 V2.0
```

If my description of the problem is incomplete, Please point me to what information do you need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to downgrade. You can run a portable version of VLC. Follow these steps:

- Download portable version of [VLC](http://portablelinuxapps.org/audiovideo/vlc)
- Copy/move vlc to your home directory.
- Right click on it and select properties.
- In properties dialog box select "Permissions" tab and enable "Allow executing file as program" like shown below

  [image]

That's it. Now run it by right click and open.

Comment: I downloaded the "VLC 1.1.5" file, changed the permissions and when y tried to execute it (I tried both double click and right click and open), nothing happend. Then, I renamed it to "VLC1_1_5" for simple execute it on terminal. When I run `$ ./VLC1_1_5` I get the following error message: `./VLC1_1_5: error while loading shared libraries: libfuse.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`

Comment: @tutucavoraz You don't have to change the permissions, Just make it executable like shown in the screenshot. I just tried it and it's working fine for me.

Comment: That portable app is for a 32 bit install only, that's why you get the error. Also no need to be root to set as executable  when stored/run from Home directory

Comment: Solved!

<pre>
`$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk libc6-i386<br/>
$ cd /tmp<br/>
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fuse/libfuse2_2.8.1-1.1ubuntu2_i386.deb<br/>
$ dpkg --extract libfuse2_2.8.1-1.1ubuntu2_i386.deb libfuse<br/>
$ sudo chown root:root libfuse/lib/lib*<br/>
$ sudo mv libfuse/lib/lib* /lib32/<br/>
$ rm -r libfuse<br/>`
</pre>

Now a can run portable VLC (thanks @basharat-sial) in my 64-bits system considering 32-bits libraries (thanks @doug fot point that).